# Add Cross Sell Block to Checkout Step Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have added a checkout step to my store where i want cross sell products. I have this block that is on the cart page for cross sell products which i would like to add in however my step is just a html file.

```
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" after="-">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="crosssell.product.addto" as="addto">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                               name="crosssell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                </block>
```

So as suggested i am going to create a controller for cross sell and then call this controller using ajax and place into my html with javascript.

```
<?php
namespace Harri\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Display extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * Constructor
 * 
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory

)
{
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->_resultFactory = $context->getResultFactory();
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * Execute view action
 * 
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 */
public function execute()
{
    $resultLayout = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_LAYOUT);
    return $resultLayout;
}
}
```

However i am currently having issues with the controller and rendering the block from xml. This needs to use below code to render the block however am not quite sure how to use it in the controller to generate my cross-sell block.

```
$resultLayout = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_LAYOUT);
return $resultLayout;
```

I can echo hello world out into my controller however cannot get my controller to render the block from the xml. Also having a lot of difficulty getting the controller to just be a blank layout with just my cross-sell block.

XML: (using a differnt block at present for testing as have not setup crosssell on this site i ma testing on)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<container name="root" label="Root">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="homeslider">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">homeslider</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
</container>
```

I have created a github with progress so far with following issues:

1. Block called from the controller redirects to controller page. Want to either have this redirect to cart when adding a product from controller or use ajax add to cart from checkout.
2. Checkout step shows both my step and the next step on same page and both highlighted when loading /checkout. I think this may be due to my module requiring dependency on magento_checkout however cant see in docs how to do this.
3. My other issue once this is all working is hiding the step if there are no cross sells or showing another block in place in this step. Will try and check weather this is empty before the checkout loads and disable the step in the js however worried about page speed with loading controller twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call a block in html file, AJAX loading the content is the way to it. Magento 2's export functionality does the same thing. When you change export entity magento has to change filter html that is rendered. so magento calls this Controller

```
Magento\ImportExport\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GetFilter
```

Observe the code in execute method. There are two key things

```
 $resultLayout = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_LAYOUT);
return $resultLayout;
```

So you are going to return a layout and NOT a page layout.

Name of your xml will be .xml
That means you will create a xml like this

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
<container name="root" label="Root">
           <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Crosssell" name="checkout.cart.crosssell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">crosssell</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="crosssell.product.addto" as="addto">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                           name="crosssell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
</container>
```

Notice that parent node is  and not 
That's it. You will have your cross sell html as response to your ajax request. Just insert the html wherever you want.

To an ajax call you can write jquery inside your html. somthing like this

```
<script>
require(['jquery'],function($){
   $.get('url/of/controller',function(response){
      //do stuff with your html
   })
})
<script>
```

If you knockout do with knockout. Or doing it with x-magento-init is even better.

Just start with a simple echo "Hello world" in your controller and it will become clear. If your controller action is route/controller/action then your layout name should be route_controller_action.xml . That's why result factory knows which layout.xml to use from your module

Comment: Ok this sounds good however i am slightly confused as to how make the ajax call within the html page to get this block?

Comment: Thanks but im still a little lost. So i need to write a controller for crosssell that returns a layout? What is the XML for here? and then in my html i call this new controller that returns that layout and update this into my html?

Comment: Yeah this is brilliant so i think i undersatnd what i am kinda doing. So i create a controller that is going to be an empty crosssell page. This controller has the xml you stated so that it renders the crosssell list. This can then be accessed on that url and i just do some jquery to spit this out on the page. However my controller.php is not showing my block as stated in xml and my html file isnt running the javascript what is going in the controller? I have updated my answer to show what i am doing

Comment: Yeah i think i need to do a bit of ground work just to get the controller sorted in a normal view just looking over that code now. Javascript wise nothing is showing in console but will leave this for now.

Comment: I have the javascript side working however just stuck on controller now... I have tried just creating a controller to show the crosssell list without any luck any chance of an example controller :P as when i drop the code suggested in i just get errors?

Comment: I have updated my code i am using an example block that isnt cross sell. Just the controller i am all over the place unsure quite how to just get it to render the blocks from xml but can get it to echo hello world to my url so that is all fine and got the javascript reading that url fine too so gettin there. Thanks for all your help tho your a legend!

Comment: Well its helloworld_index_display.xml as this is my module name at present. It throws an error on the controller page if i make a mistake in there tho. Will change it to route see what] happens.

Comment: I changed it but still had a blank page. If i change it to my helloworld one and just make a mistake it throws an error so i'm guessing that is correct xml name?

Comment: sorry yeah that is it got confused

Comment: I have got no error now just a blank page which i  can echo stuff into from controller using that code above. The page is just blank html with an empty body.

Comment: Oh found the bug. You dont have template assigned to your block. I took your code and just added template like this `<block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="homeslider" template="Magecrafts_Debug::content.phtml"/>`  Of course change it to your template and your module. Also `<container name="root" label="Root">` element is import in layout

Comment: That block was just calling a static block form admin cms seemed to work on homepage. I have tried this without luck also however.

Comment: Yeah have tried that sure its not an issue in my controller? Thinks its me thats going wrong on my end ha

Comment: Cheeeerrrs will do

Comment: https://github.com/harrigo/crosssell-checkout

Comment: Made some progress here. Was maybe an issue with my route i changed it and everything started working. Nothing goes smooth tho adding to cart redirects to my controller from checkout which i have to loook into now but thanks so much for all help!